# I have an unhandled exception error while creating new flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1t3N.png)

I have tried every possible solution that I found on internet. Since I am not a tech savy guy so I have almost tried possible solution still no luck.

Comment: did you add flutter sdk path (C:\src\flutter\bin) in environment variables path ?

Comment: Sometimes errors like these can happen due to files being in use, you could try restarting and, if that doesn't work, reinstalling the flutter SDK. That being said, [you should never post images for code/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), instead you should post it as code - [see here how](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).